# losing data when comparing a column with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file and all I want to do is compare the third column and see if it's equal to 1 or 0, so I just simply used

```
awk '$3 == 1 { print $0 }' input > output1
awk '$3 == 0 { print $0 }' input > output2
```

This is part of a bash script and I'm certain there is a more elegant approach to this, but the code above should get the job done, only it does not. `input` has 425 rows of text, the third column in input is always a 1 or 0, therefore the total number of rows in `output1` + `output2` should be 425. But I get 417 rows.

Here is a sample of input (all of it is just one row, and there are 425 such rows):

```
out_first.dat   1 1 0.000000 265075.000000  6.000000e-01 1.005205e-03   9.000000e-01 9.000000e-01   2.889631e+00 -2.423452e+00  3.730018e+00 -1.532915e+00
```

Comment: First of all change from $3==1 and $3==0 remove " from them. Also show us the complete sample Input_file.

Comment: I changed my code to $3==1 and $3==0 which does not appear to make any difference. The output is just a bunch of text, but I'll add an example above. Thanks.

Comment: There may be some `space` in the rest rows.

Comment: try this `awk '$3==1{print $0 >>"output1"} $3==0{print $0 >>"output2"}' inputfile`

Comment: If $3 can **only** be 1 or 0 then that'd be `awk '{print > ("output"($3?1:2))}' file`.

Answer (score 2):

if $3 is 1 or 0, it will be equal to its square, prints to output1/2.  If not prints to other for inspection.

```
awk `$3*$3==$3{print > "output"(2-$3); next} {print > "other"}' file
```

if `$3*$3==$3` is confusing, change to `$3==0 || $3===1`

for the curious `$3==0 || $3===1` can be written as `$3*($3-1)==0` from which the above follows.

Comment: That's clever!  Almost too clever - your final line is probably a good stepping-stone to understanding.